# caching AD credentials on 2012 r2 File Server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, file-server

I am setting up a fileserver at a remote branch office that has very very limited bandwidth

Is there a way to store the 10 or so users authentication credentials locally on the File Server so that the machine does not have to be on VPN 24/7.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the cached logon count. By default it is set to 10 and the maximum value is 50

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\ 

ValueName: CachedLogonsCount
Data Type: REG_SZ
Values: 0 - 50
```

You will still need to logon once per account though.

Alternatively you can deploy a RODC to the site but it has an initial bandwidth hit. On a RODC you can select which passwords should be sync'ed locally.

Comment: I've been eyeballing RODC but it seems complex, as for the Cached Logon I tried hitting a shared file after i was able to get to it once (while on vpn) and i was blocked (without vpn running)  would i need the users to login to the server itself to cache the pw?

Comment: Yes, you need the users to login. RODC is not very complex but you will need to make sure it (the RODC) stays healthy seeing that the VPN will not be online 24/7

Comment: Do you know of any online tutorials for RODC that are specific to this type of request.  I am working to setup site to site vpn that will be up but if for some reason they lose internet (which sometimes they do for up to a week) that they are not dead in the water.   Would such an outage have any adverse effect on the RODC